# monthly frequency time series data frame, fill NaNs with specific values

Tags: pandas

How do I pass values to months from April to September. 
I would like the April value equals to 42000, May=41000, June=61200, July=71000,August=71000

```
df.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=60, step=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a mapping like this, you would typically define a dictionary and map the values. Use `.split` to get the month part of the date and `fillna` to fill only the missing values.

#### Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-Jan', '2018-Feb', '2018-Mar', '2018-Apr', '2018-May',
                            '2018-Jun', '2018-Jul', '2018-Aug', '2018-Sep'],
                   'Value': [75267.169, 42258.868, 43793]+[np.NaN]*6})
```

#### Code:

```
d = {'Apr': 42000, 'May': 41000, 'Jun': 61200, 'Jul': 71000, 'Aug': 71000}
df['Value'] = df.Value.fillna(df.Date.str.split('-').str[1].map(d))
```

#### Output:

```
       Date      Value
0  2018-Jan  75267.169
1  2018-Feb  42258.868
2  2018-Mar  43793.000
3  2018-Apr  42000.000
4  2018-May  41000.000
5  2018-Jun  61200.000
6  2018-Jul  71000.000
7  2018-Aug  71000.000
8  2018-Sep        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

super simple and ugly way to do it using `pd.DataFrame.iloc`

```
to_fill = [42000,41000,61200,71000,71000]    
df.iloc[54:59,1] = to_fill
```